# Python library import fails when executed with 'pOpen' sub process from another Python script

Tags: python, import, popen

I have a Python service that needs to run another Python script (*in a completely different folder path*) using "pOpen". That file needs to import multiple classes in different folders. 'pOpen' fails to run the script with an error message that import fails as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\basic_detection\creatorop.py", line 2, in <module> from detection_Inference import * File "C:\basic_detection\detection_Inference.py", 
line 13, in <module> from notebook_utils import segmentation_map_to_image, to_rgb ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook_utils'. Try again.
```

I am calling the script to run with the following statement :
process = Popen(command_arg_list, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

The file I am calling is

> creatorop.py

The header of the file is as follows :

```
import argparse
from detection_Inference import *
#import mytracker as m
sys.path.append(".")
sys.path.append("../utils")
sys.path.append("./utils")
from notebook_utils import segmentation_map_to_image, to_rgb

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
```

**Important** : Each folder in this source path includes empty **init**.py files.

The folder structure where creatorop.py resides is as follows :

```
C:\basic_detection
> creatorop.py
> detection_inference.py
> __initi__py
<utils> 
---> notebook_utils.py 
---> __init__.py
```

I appended all possible paths, including the 'utils' folder, but the system did not see it.

When I run the creatorop.py in its folder, it runs without any issues. This only happens when I run it from 'pOpen' from another application.

Any help ?

Comment: What directory are you in when you run this script?  It clearly expects to be run in the `utils` directory, so just do an `os.chdir` before you call `pOpen`.

Comment: I am calling the creatorop.py file with the full path from another folder entirely out of the creatorop.py file path. But creatorop.py file should import files in its folder path which is correct

Comment: Yes, but when you say "../utils", that's relative to the "current working directory", NOT to the directory that contains the script.  You can COMPUTE that from the `__file__` variable, but it's not automatic.

Comment: When I added the absolute path, it worked. Let me play with __file__ as well.